# Cakephp session troubles

Tags: php, session, cakephp

I can't understand the strange behaviour of sessions in CakePHP controller:

```
class UsersController extends AppController
{
    public $helpers = array('Session');
    public $components = array('Session'); 

    public function Do() {
        $this->Session->write('Foo', 'Bar');
        $_SESSION['Foo2'] = 'Bar2';

        echo $this->Session->read('Foo');
        echo $_SESSION['Foo2'];
    }
};
```

First echo outputs nothing and the second one - `Bar2`. Why does native `$_SESSION` works but through CakePHP interface it's not available?

Comment: it should work no problem in code , could u check again

Comment: Do you have sessions properly set up on `app/config/core.php`?

Comment: @bfavaretto Yeah, it's set to `php`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(This answer assumes CakePHP 1.3)**

You said in the comments that you have `Session.save` set to `php` on your config file. In the same file, you should have `Session.start` set to `true`. If you don't, you have two options:

- Actually setting `Session.start` to `true` on the config file, or
- Calling `$this->Session->activate()` from the controller before using the Session component.

References:

http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1465/Session (oddly, `Session.start` and `activate()` are only documented for the session helper, but they apply to the component too).
http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/931/CakePHP-Core-Configuration-Variables